# How to run a script for every PC listed in .csv file?

Tags: csv, vbscript

I'm looking for help in being able to run a script against every PC listed in a csv using VBScript. Currently we are using a small script which we found on the "Hey, Scripting Guy blog" which gathers us the correct information regarding PC to Printer relationship but only on one manually specificed PC. This is a breakdown on what we're trying to achieve:

- Take a list of PCs which are stored in a CSV.
- Run the script listed below to query the values in the CSV and run the script against that value.
- Once it has run the script against the values within the file, move on to the next PC in the CSV list.

  ```
  strComputer = "PC-13699"

  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

  Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Printer")

  For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
  If objPrinter.Attributes And 64 Then 
  strPrinterType = "Local"
  Else
  strPrinterType = "Network"
  End If
  Wscript.Echo objPrinter.Name & " -- " & strPrinterType
  Next
  ```

I haven't had much experience with VBS at all so I'm a complete novice with this language so please bear with me if I'm sounding stupid. Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: You need to show a line from the CSV file--anyone wanting to help won't know exactly how to write the code you've asked for unless they know what column the computernames are in.  Additionally, you can probably figure out how to read the csv into an array and loop through the array by Googling--lots of examples out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your CSV has a field named `ComputerName` for the computer names you could modify your script [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24014830/1630171):

```
filename = "C:\path\to\your.csv"

Set csv = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(filename)

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs   = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & csv.ParentFolder.Path & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & csv.Name & "]", conn

Do Until rs.EOF
  strComputer = rs.Fields("ComputerName").Value

  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

  Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Printer")

  For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
    If objPrinter.Attributes And 64 Then 
      strPrinterType = "Local"
    Else
      strPrinterType = "Network"
    End If
    Wscript.Echo objPrinter.Name & " -- " & strPrinterType
  Next

  rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
conn.Close
```

Comment: Thank you, this will save us a large amount of time gathering this information.